# Converting arcs to straight line segments?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, fme-form, oracle-spatial, geomedia

I have a large number of geometries, currently stored in Oracle, some of which contain arc segments.

I need to convert these geometries into LRS (Linear Referencing System) format so I would like to convert all the arcs to straight line segments.

I may have to write something in PL/SQL but, being a lazy sort, I was rather hoping someone had done this before.

Doesn't have to be in PL/SQL, I also have ArcGIS for Desktop, MapInfo, GeoMedia and FME if any of those would do it.

Comment: Just discovered ArcStroker in FME which looks like it may do the trick (once I've fixed the other problems with invalid geometries)

Comment: We use ArcStroker in FME to move CAD to GIS pure arcs to very small lines to preserve the arcs shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **FME**, this is as simple as connecting your data to an **[ArcStroker](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/arcstroker.htm)** transformer.

From the help page:

> Converts arc features into lines replacing the feature geometry with a
>   series of edges interpolated along the arc boundary. Ellipse features
>   are converted into polygons by interpolating edges along the
>   elliptical boundary.
>
> If the input geometry is a path consisting of arcs and lines, or an
>   area whose boundary is such a path, then any arcs in the path will be
>   stroked, also using the Number of Interpolated Edges given.

[image]

There are a few parameters to allow you to determine how the arcs are stroked.

Prior to running it through the ArcStroker, you may want to filter your geometry using a **[GeometryFilter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/geometryfilter.htm)** transformer.  You can port the arcs separately, then join them back to your lines later on.  Though, this may not be necessary.

Comment: Not sure why I never found ArcStroker before. I've definitely been through this on previous occasions, but then I always have a problem guessing what Safe have decided to call various transformers.
Anyhow, it seems to work a treat of the geometries I've managed to patch up so far.

Answer (score 7):

In ArcGIS for Desktop, you can use the tool [Densify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000).

> Adds vertices along line or polygon features. Also replaces curve
>   segments (Bezier, circular arcs, and elliptical arcs) with line
>   segments.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! I think this sufficiently answers the question, since the link elaborates on the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you can copy your arcs into a shapefile and then from shapefile back to its original format then you should find that the true curves are now short segments.

I did this recently using the **Copy Features** tool of ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 to convert a true curve to a polyline of short segments in a file geodatabase.

The storage format is different but the principle remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, use ogr2ogr and apply -segmentize option (recommended): 
http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Second, use Spatialite and apply ST_Segementize():
http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=spatialite_tut01

Third, use PostGIS and apply ST_CurveToLine(): 
http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_CurveToLine.html