# How to convert a compound geometry (Oracle) to a geometry made of straight line segments only?

Tags: oracle-spatial, geometry-conversion

I have an Oracle Spatial table containing compound geometries (i.e. geometries containing both straight lines segments and arcs) that I want to project in another reference system.

Using `SDO_CS.TRANSFORM` returns:

```
13294. 00000 -  "cannot transform geometry containing circular arcs"
*Cause:    It is impossible to transform a 3-point representation of
           a circular arc without distortion.
*Action:   Make sure a geometry does not contain circular arcs.
```

Is there a way to convert the arcs to straight lines with a SQL request?

I've read [Converting arcs to straight line segments?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/converting-arcs-to-straight-line-segments) which mentions using FME or ArcGIS Desktop to do the conversion but I don't have access to such tools. What I am looking for is a way to do that only with Oracle Spatial (I do not care if the resulting segments are raw approximations of the original geometries).

Comment: Search from the web found SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_objgeom.htm#i867686. I would try that.

Comment: Could you write some notes about how you used SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY? I haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: @user30184 The function takes a tolerance parameter as second parameter (which defines a minimum difference distance in original projection units under which coordinates are considered the same, and a string to define an arc_tolerance (explained on your link), in the end `SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(GEOMETRIE, 0.1, 'arc_tolerance=0.05 unit=km')` made my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that converts arc into straight segments is SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY. Documentation for Oracle 12c is at
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/GUID-97E8BF76-34B8-48CA-94A4-96F16B01B60C.htm#SPATL1108

There are two formats for the function

```
SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(     
  geom    IN SDO_GEOMETRY,      
  dim     IN SDO_DIM_ARRAY       
  params  IN VARCHAR2      
) RETURN SDO_GEOMETRY;
```

or

```
SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(
  geom    IN SDO_GEOMETRY,      
  tol     IN NUMBER       
  params  IN VARCHAR2      
) RETURN SDO_GEOMETRY;
```

Diminfo is rather painful to write by hand and therefore the latter format suits better for ad hoc queries.

An usage example with tolerance=0.1 (vertices which are closer that 0.1 meter from each other are considered to be in the same place) and arc_tolerance of 50 m (at maximum 50 meters shift is accepted due to conversion of curve into polyline)

```
SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(GEOMETRIE, 0.1, 'arc_tolerance=0.05 unit=km')
```